# Method in Django to display all attributes' values belonging to a created object?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm

Is there a certain method in Django which allows for retrieving/displaying all attributes' values belonging to an object created via Django?

In Python shell, I used the following:

```
>>> print(p.first_name, p.last_name, p.software_name)
Linus Torvalds Linux
```

p is the created object with the attributes *first_name, last_name, software_name*. I already created several models which were applied to a specific database in *mysql*.

I would like to learn of other ways to display such information.

Comment: `print(dir(p))` might help you..

Comment: It does not help.

Answer (score 26):

The Python built-in special attribute [`object.__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) can retrieve all the attributes of the object, as a dictionary.

```
p.__dict__
# returns {'first_name': 'Linus', 'last_name': 'Torvalds', 'software_name': 'Linux'}
```

Alternatively, use the Python built-in function [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars), which returns the `__dict__` of the object, giving the same result.

```
vars(p)
```

For a QuerySet, you may consider displaying the attributes of one of the QuerySet items, e.g.:

```
q.first().__dict__
# or
vars(q.first())
```

Comment: This deserves more upvotes for solving the other case that the first solution doesn't solve- e.g. when using a `.get`

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much what I'd imagined getting when seeing the title of this question. +1 from me.

Answer (score 23):

A bit late, but as none of the answers mentioned the easiest way to do that:

```py
>>> # assuming your object was already saved in the database and p is the QuerySet
>>> # with your object
>>> p.values()
<QuerySet [{'first_name': 'Linus', 'last_name': 'Torvalds', 'software_name': 'Linux'}]>
```

Comment: This works for me when the QuerySet has a list of objects. However, when `p` is the actual object, it tells me it has no attribute `values`. For instance, if works for `p = Model.objects.filter(<condition>)`, but if `p = Model.objects.filter(<condition>).first()` this does not work

Comment: Yes, that's why in the comment above I mentioned `assuming (...) p is the QuerySet with your object"`. `values()` will only work with QuerySets. You can filter a QuerySet that will have only one object.

Comment: A note for django learners - `Model.objects.filter(id=p.id).values()` makes a call to database. Don't use this approach if you already have `p` as a model instance.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the inbuilt python **dir()** method

**dir(object)**

Comment: `dir(object)` returns a list of the attributes' names, but the attributes' values are not included.

Answer (score 1):

You can define `__str__` method for the corresponding model class, like in the following.

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    software_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name + " " + self.software_name
```

You can achieve your desire like following on ***django Shell***, assuming your first entry is *Linus Torvalds Linux* in your database.

```
from main_app.models import User
e = User.objects.get(pk=1)
e
```

Answer (score -1):

There is model_to_dict function you can use. Check this [answer](https://django-model-to-dict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

This module packages it as a mixin : [django-model-to-dict](https://django-model-to-dict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Once your object is in dictionary form, a print or any processing should be easier.